# Field gets overwritten when opening audiostream in OBOE

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, oboe

I am using OBOE to build an sound app. I have in my AudioEngine.cpp defined couple of fields (audiosample - float, starting position field - int field, sample lengths field - int field etc.) However one of the fields (sample lengts - int field) gets overwritten when I open the audiostream with playbackBuilder.
See code

```
 AudioStreamBuilder playbackBuilder;

playbackBuilder.setPerformanceMode(PerformanceMode::LowLatency);
playbackBuilder.setSharingMode(SharingMode::Exclusive);
playbackBuilder.setChannelCount(ChannelCount::Mono);
playbackBuilder.setFormat(AudioFormat::Float);
playbackBuilder.setSampleRate(44100);
playbackBuilder.setCallback(this);
LOGD("samplelength[46]=%d",sampleLengths_[46]);
Result result = playbackBuilder.openStream(&outputStream_);
if (result != Result::OK) {
    LOGE("Error opening output stream_ %s",convertToText(result));
    return false;
}
LOGD("samplelength[46]=%d",sampleLengths_[46]);
auto setBufferSizeResult = outputStream_->setBufferSizeInFrames(outputStream_->getFramesPerBurst() * 2);
if (setBufferSizeResult) {
    LOGD("New buffer size is %d in frames",setBufferSizeResult.value());
}
```

The output from logcat is:

```
D/OboeAudio: samplelength[46]=2393
D/OboeAudio: openStream() OUTPUT -------- OboeVersion1.4.0 --------
D/OboeAudio: AAudioLoader():  dlopen(libaaudio.so) returned 0x73861583b1301b8f
I/cesthingsplaye: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
D/OboeAudio: AudioStreamAAudio() call isSupported()
I/AAudio: AAudioStreamBuilder_openStream() called ----------------------------------------
I/AudioStreamBuilder: rate   =  44100, channels  = 1, format   = 5, sharing = EX, dir = OUTPUT
I/AudioStreamBuilder: device =      0, sessionId = -1, perfMode = 12, callback: ON with frames = 0
I/AudioStreamBuilder: usage  =      1, contentType = 2, inputPreset = 6, allowedCapturePolicy = 0
D/AudioStreamBuilder: build() EXCLUSIVE sharing mode not supported. Use SHARED.
D/AudioStreamTrack: open(), request notificationFrames = -8, frameCount = 0
I/cesthingsplaye: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on ClassLinker for 26.177ms
I/cesthingsplaye: WaitForGcToComplete blocked HeapTrim on ProfileSaver for 5.568ms
W/AudioTrack: createTrack_l(0): AUDIO_OUTPUT_FLAG_FAST denied by server; frameCount 0 -> 1772
W/AudioStreamTrack: open() flags changed from 0x00000104 to 0x00000000
W/AudioStreamTrack: open() perfMode changed from 12 to 10
I/AAudio: AAudioStreamBuilder_openStream() returns 0 = AAUDIO_OK for s#1 ----------------
D/OboeAudio: AudioStreamAAudio.open() app    format = 2
D/OboeAudio: AudioStreamAAudio.open() sample rate   = 44100
D/OboeAudio: AudioStreamAAudio.open() capacity      = 1772
D/OboeAudio: AudioStreamAAudio.open: AAudioStream_Open() returned AAUDIO_OK, mAAudioStream = 0x731d2dd580
D/OboeAudio: samplelength[46]=0
```

NB: Value 2393 of the 46th element is exactly what I expect it to be. It is not a random number. It is initialized with the lines below. However it gets overwritteb (actualy the whole field) when opening stream.

This is the initialization code for this particular field - sampleLengths_ that gets overwritten:

```
sampleLengthsArrayLen_ = sampleLengthArrayLen;
sampleLengths_ = new int[sampleLengthArrayLen];
sampleLengths_ = sampleLengths;
```

Any hints why this happens? Bad memory mnagement?
Thanks a lot.
j

Comment: Please post your initialization code for `sampleLength`

Comment: @donturner code added to the question

Comment: You still haven't posted your initialization code. Where are the values actually set? What types are used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is instead of C-style array to use Standard Library container. In my case its *std::vector* as I don't know the exact size at compile time. So I obtain an C-style array from JNI and create a vector , in this way the values are not overwritten . C-style array do not somehow offer protection for the data when opening stream in OBOE.

```
vector<int> sampleLengths_;
sampleLengthsArrayLen_ = sampleLengthArrayLen;
sampleLengths_.assign(sampleLengths,sampleLengths+sampleLengthArrayLen);
```

Comment: 1) "as I don't know the exact size at compile time" <- if you don't know the exact size at compile time how were you declaring your C-style array? 2) Although you've answered your own question it doesn't explain why that memory was being overwritten. It'd be better to figure that out and post _why_ that happened.

Comment: 3) "C-style array do not somehow offer protection for the data when opening stream in OBOE." <- this behaviour has nothing to do with Oboe. If Oboe were able to randomly overwrite validly declared and initialised variables in your own program then it'd be a very serious bug. Please (3rd time of asking) post your C-style array initialisation code and we can figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suspect that this is because you haven't initialised `sampleLengths` so the values you're reading are actually just random pieces of memory which get changed during program execution.

C++ supports initialization of an int array to all zeros by doing:

```
int sampleLengths[10] = { 0 };
```

Comment: Ok I will look at that. But the value 2393 of the position 46 is exactly what I want and expect. But after opening the stream it gets overwritten.

Comment: Is your array length 46 by any chance? If so, writing to `sampleLengths[46]` is an off-by-one error because that's the 47th index (arrays are zero-indexed). You can read/write it, sure (same way you can read/write to any address in memory), but because the memory isn't allocated it'll be overwritten. This is the problem with using C-style arrays - there is no bounds checking. Consider using `std::array<int, array_length>` instead.

Comment: oh no. array has length of 93. I checked 46th as kind-of-a-middle element. I will check std::array

Comment: standard library solved the problem , particulary std::vector see my answer. Thanks a lot!